# Migrating TFVC Code from TFS to VSTS with History

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

I need to migrate tfvc code from tfs to vsts with the history intact.

I am aware of OpsHub Migration Utility https://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/

Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of tools that help with TFs to VSTS migrations. Currently "the best" depending on your situation is the ability to import a TFS collection and create a VSTS account from it.

See also this other post which asks the same question for work items, the same set of tools tends to apply:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37446754/736079
- [TFS to VSTS migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/migration-import?view=vsts) - The official import option which will import 1 project collection into 1 VSTS account. It automatically imports everything stored in the backup. At the point of writing this, the TFS must be upgraded to TFS 2018 and some work item template customizations must be removed (there are a few well documented features unavailable on VSTS).
- Use the [TFS Integration Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe) - Will work for most TFVC situations, though it will lose data associated to your checkins (original checkin dat eand time are lost due to the way TFVC works, the data will be appended to the checkin comment.
- Use a 3rd party solution - Out of the available options currently [OpsHub](http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/products/vsomigrationutility) offers the most complete solution. For test case and source control link migration you're looking at the commercial edition, which comes at a steep price. It still has a [long list of known issues](http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/products/vsomigrationutility) and last time I tried it, I ran into numerous issues which required their support to resolve them. If you're only after source control history, then [Timely Migrations](http://www.timelymigration.com/) is also worth looking at.

There are specialized TFS consultants who live off these kinds of migrations if your current state of the work items is precious to you, [then you could reach out to them](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/migration-integration-solutions).

See also:

- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/adopting-vsts

Comment: Hi Jesse, lets say I use the official import option which imports 1 project collection into 1 VSTS account. Can I later on import the same project collection into the same VSTS account? I want to have active team projects on-premises and the inactive ones I want to migrate to VSTS. So if I used the import service to import my collection, can I later on use the same procedure to import the same collection but now with newer team projects that are not existing in my current VSTS account?

Comment: No each project collection you  import yields it's own a organization (new name for accounts). In order to upload part of a collection you first have to split it, resulting in multiple collections pre-import and thus multiple organizations post-import.