# TFS Work Item Migration from 2018 to Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, migration, tfs-workitem, workitem, tfs-migration

we are trying to migrate from TFS to Azure Devops and as part of the migration want to migrate work items. I had tried using VSTS-work-item-migrator and vsts-sync-migration tool for migration but couldn't be succesfull in doing that as there are some customized WIT's in current TFS. 
Can anyone suggest what would be best approach to do migrate without any data loss.

Note: We don't want to use import database approach.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the import database approach? Your two only options are to either convert your TFS projects to OOB then use a tool or you will need to use the database import. The only way to currently keep customizations (use Hosted XML) is through the import service.

Answer (score 0):

For your demand,I am afraid there is no such tool available at present.These migration tools should not recognize your custom process.So it is not feasible to migrate custom work items to azure devops via tools.

To migrate complete data from TFs to azure devops, it is recommended to use the method of importing the database.

This is guided in other [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446325/how-to-migrate-work-items-from-tfs-to-visual-studio-team-services) and [docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/devops/migrate/). For details,you can refer to these.

[TFS to VSTS migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/migrate/migration-import?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) - The official import option which will import 1 project collection into 1 VSTS account. It automatically imports everything stored in the backup. At the point of writing this, the TFS must be upgraded to TFS 2018 and some work item template customizations must be removed (there are a few well documented features unavailable on VSTS).

Comment: Thanks Hugh, I had never dione migration before and reason for not opting the database import is that we want have clean setup in VSTS and as part of that want to migrate WIT's & SOurce code from old TFS.

Answer (score 0):

There is tool call nkd-agilty migration tool which is used from all kinds of migration from tfs/AzureDevOps to another
https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/