# How can I migrate test cases to Azure Dev ops from Test Manager?

Tags: testing, tfs, azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager, azure-boards

I have hundreds of test cases on Test Manager/TFS. And now we are moving on to Azure Dev ops. How can I easily bring in those test cases to Azure devops?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to migrate from TFS/Azure DevOps Server to Azure DevOps Service is to use the [full fidelity import service which takes a complete Project Collection from the server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-overview?view=azure-devops).

If that isn't an option, you can migrate a copy of these items with most of their details in tact. It will cause some changes to your test-cases (such as date created) and is generally a more tenuous process. These options are all described here:

- [How to migrate work items from TFS to Visual Studio Team Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446325/how-to-migrate-work-items-from-tfs-to-visual-studio-team-services/37446754#37446754)

Comment: Also if you need to migrate test results, note that is much more complex and should be avoided.

Comment: Only the full fidelity import will fully import the runs and past results without dataloss.