# how can i migrate my current tfs 2013 custom work items to 2015 visual studio cloud?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I currently use TFS 2013 with custom work items for bugs, change request, requirements and features.  I am wondering if I can migrate them to visual studio cloud 2015? is there a tool within VS or 3rd party that can do this?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO, but a quick google turns up quite a few tools: https://nkdagility.com/vsts-sync-migration-tools/

Comment: What's the  "*visual studio cloud 2015*"? Are you meaning VSTS(https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/) a cloud-based  TFS solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to migrate work items from TFS to Visual Studio Team Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446325/how-to-migrate-work-items-from-tfs-to-visual-studio-team-services)

Answer (score 0):

If you are meaning the vsts. Possibly duplicate with this question: [How to migrate work items from TFS to VS Team Services (VS Online)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446325/how-to-migrate-work-items-from-tfs-to-vs-team-services-vs-online) . There has been perfect answer from *jessehouwing*, suggest use one of  below three ways as he suggested:

> - Use Excel for import/export - Will work for most work items, you    loose attachments and work item links other than parent/child. The
>     trick is to extract from one Project Collection then copy all fields, 
>     except the ID to an Excel sheet bound to the target project
>     collection. You will need to fix all Identity fields (works best when 
>     users have the exact same display name on premise as in VSTS) and
>     you'll have to import once with state new and then past the current
>     state/reason over the just imported values and sync again. Test
>     Cases, Plans, Suites and Shared Steps will not be imported with their 
>     relations in tact. [The approach would be very similar to this
>     one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625770/creating-a-task-board-template/36726760#36726760)
> - Use the [TFS Integration Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe) - Will work for most work item types,    though it will loose custom kanban states and tags. Test
>     cases,    Shared steps and their relations will not be imported. This
>     option    will allow you to import import work items and source code
>     with their    relationships in tact.
> - Use a 3rd party solution - Out of the available options currently    [OpsHub](http://opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/) offers the most complete solution. For test case and
>     source    control link migration you're looking at the commercial
>     edition,    which comes at a steep price. It still has [a long list of
>     known    issues](http://opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/) and last time I tried it, I ran into numerous
>     issues which    required their support to resolve them. PS: You can aslo try the tool as *Dave* suggested in the comment: [VSTS Sync Migration Tools](https://nkdagility.com/vsts-sync-migration-tools/)